# Does LLVM have test coverage support in Xcode 4?

Tags: ios, xcode, llvm, clang

Does clang/llvm have support to produce test coverage files as was the case with GCC which produced .gcov files. if yes how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hear that XCode is still under NDA, but I can talk about LLVM and Clang. LLVM now knows how to emit .gcno files when compiling, and .gcda files when your program is run (linked against libprofile_rt). Inside LLVM, this uses the data from debug info to associate the code with the file and line number information.

To use it, you'll need LLVM and Clang from SVN HEAD. That clang should support the same flags that gcc does for building with coverage; --coverage will do, or you can use -ftest-coverge and -fprofile-arcs individually. For linking, GCC supported -lgcov which is wrong for clang+llvm and should be replaced with --coverage, as the LLVM version of the library is named profile_rt, not libgcov.

Comment: Can you explain how to get that working with an iOS project? I tried building llvm/clang from source but I get a x64 binary. What flags do I pass to ./configure to get i386 support (for the iPhone/iPad simulator) rolled in? Also linking against the already supplied lib profile_rt.dylib crashes with Library not loaded: @executable_path/../lib/libprofile_rt.dylib

Comment: @Dan Yes/No. Yes I made it work for a month then Apple released an update which broke it. I returned to S/O with more questions and was able to get it working again and Apple updated the tools and broke it again. I forget where I left off, honestly as I've moved onto Android.